# Где найти нужные директивы MySQL?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, openserver, ini

Занимаюсь установкой *zumro CRM*. Сервер сконфигурировал. Теперь требования к настройке *БД*:

```
**Failed Required Services**    
Database default collation is: utf8_general_ci . Database default collation
should not be in: utf8_general_ci   
FAIL
Database log_bin=on. Either set log_bin=off or set log_bin_trust_function_creators=on.  
FAIL

**Failed Optional Services**
Database max_sp_recursion_depth size is: 0 minimum requirement is: 20   
FAIL
Database thread_stack value is: 196608 minimum requirement is: 524288   
FAIL
Database optimizer_search_depth value is 62. It is required to be set to 0. 
FAIL
Database does not support LOAD LOCAL INFILE.    
FAIL
```

Увидел `max_sp_recursion_depth` в таблицах с конфигами, но поменять нельзя.

Где это всё искать и настраивать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: За такое разрабов бить надо, имхо. Разумное требование thread_stack при запросе на рекурсивные хранимые процедуры и сама настройка max_sp_recursion_depth. И это всё настаивается в конфигах сервера. Почему поменять не можешь?

Answer (score 1):

Директивы MySQL устанавливаются в конфигурационном файле my.cnf (my.ini для Windows). В случае Linux искать этот файл следует в /etc/my.cnf или /etc/mysql/my.cnf, иногда он может быть размещен в каталоге данных /var/lib/mysql.

Если обнаружить его не удается, следует поискать в списке процессов mysqld и посмотреть не передан ли путь к этому файлу в параметрах к серверу

```
ps aux | grep mysqld
```

Как вариант его можно просто поискать на жестком диске

```
find / -name my.cnf -print
```

Если файла нигде нет, его можно просто создать (лучше по пути /etc/my.cnf).

Внутри файл разбит на секции, начало которых обозначается названием, заключенным в квадратные скобки. Секция, задающая директивы сервера называется `[mysqld]`. Если внутри секции отсутствует нужная вам директива, ее можно смело заводить. Изменения вступают в силу после перезагрузки сервера.